# UI Router multiple url using single state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have to use multiple url like users, users/add, users/edit into one view i.e users. I have enter the below code in my js. Though it is handling users/add, users/edit by taking add and edit as parameters. But it is not handling '/' as we have empty parameters for users.

Please find the ui route code below:-

```
.state('/users', {
            url: "/users/:param",
            templateUrl: ADMIN_ASSET_URL+"templates/users.html",
            data: { pageTitle: 'Users', pageHead: 'Users', currTab: 'users'},
            controller: "UsersController",
            onEnter: function($state)
            {
                if(GLOBAL.checkId.toString() == 'false')
                {
                    $state.go('/');
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Hey users is not parameter it is the part of url so '/' will not redirect you to this path :-P

If you want users as parameter use "/:users/:param"

Comment: In url, users/users will not looks good. Is there any possiblities to handle '/'?

Comment: You'll need to define one more root without slash to handle this.